# CakePHP URL rewriting in root (HTdocs) folder MAMP

Tags: cakephp-1.3

I try to do what I thought to be the simplest thing ever: Download CakePHP 1.3.10 (also tried this unsuccessfully with 1.3.9), getting the content of the download folder and paste them in the htdocs folder in MAMP 1.9.6. (OSX 10.8).

I try to put my website in the MAMP htdocs root as it replicates the eventual production environment best:
localhost/
www.example.com/

Nevertheless, when I go to localhost's root folder in my browser, I see the 'welcome to CakePHP' standard homepage without CSS and URL rewriting. I baked a model/controller/view (in this order) for a table.

When I try to reach this view (localhost/achievements)...I get the 'page does not exist' error.

This ALL worked when I put the website in a subfolder (original download folder).

I am stuck.

I have read about the following on this issue:
possibly MAMP does not have permission from Apache
htaccess issue (how can I change a .htaccess in CakePHP? can't find them)

10 beers for the winning answer, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll just guess that you copy and pasted the *contents* of the Cake folder, **missing the `.htaccess` file that is hidden in Finder by default**. Copy the *entire* contents of the folder using the terminal, including all hidden files.

```
$ cp Downloads/cake/* Sites
```

Comment: didn't not work for me. cake is showing its homepage but its not loading any css js and images.